# svn errors out strangely

Tags: svn

> unknown command: 'svn-commit.tmp'

I have never seen this type of output from svn ci. svn ci is just an alias for svn commit. Anyway, if you know how to fix this, that would be amazing. Until then, I cannot commit any code lol. I looked around on Google for others having this error but I didn't find anything.

Running svn cleanup doesn't fix anything

Comment: `'svn-commit.tmp'` is the file that you put commit comments in, dunno why it's taken as a command here, can you post the command you are executing? just `svn ci`?

Comment: Sure, the exact command I am running is:
svn ci plugins/ site_resources/
There are two files under these directories in question:
--plugins/smarty/templates/editpage.tpl
--site_resources/js/editors.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that the `EDITOR` (or `SVN_EDITOR`, etc.) environment variable is set to `svn-commit.tmp`? (This environment variable specifies which editor you want to use to edit the commit message.)

Though on Linux, at least, you would get a more meaningful error message:

```
sh: svn-commit.tmp: not found
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: system('svn-commit.tmp svn-commit.tmp') returned 32512
```

Perhaps you are on Windows, this is the problem, and the error message is terse?

Comment: I don't think that the environment variable is off. I have my ~/.bash_profile setup as follows:

export SVN_EDITOR=svn

I am running on MacOSX
Thanks for the great question and your help!

Comment: I ran sudo updatedb which is a symlink I created to update the local locate database. Then I ran locate svn-commit.tmp. This yielded 0 results. So, basically, there is no such file on my system

Comment: I don't think `svn-commit.tmp` exists - I thought that svn was trying to run that as though it were an editor. `SVN_EDITOR` needs to be be a text editor, not `svn` itself.

Comment: Great idea Richard,
I ran export SVN_EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim. My mistake for not doing this earlier. I am still getting an error when committing though: Unknown command: 'svn-commit.tmp' returned 256

Comment: I filed a bug report over at tigris: http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3703

Comment: Interestingly, svn ci somefile anotherfile andanother -m "my comment" does not cause the error but this is a horrible way to comment multiple files.

Comment: Using `-m` won't cause the error as in that case you're specifying a commit message on the command line - i.e. `svn` doesn't need to run a text editor.

Comment: Richard, yes, you are correct and doing this also prevents the issue from occurring. Seems to me that this is warrant enough for the Tigris developers to look into it but I guess they feel otherwise since my bug was marked as invalid in their issue tracker: http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3703

Comment: @syn4k the best place to take issues like this is the svn users mailing list which can help debug it.  If there's an issue with svn itself and not your environment, which would be determined there, then we can fix it in svn.  We just don't like to use the issue tracker as a place to get help, otherwise we would be inundated with tickets.

Answer (score 4):

The `EDITOR` or `SVN_EDITOR` env variables should reference a text editor, like `/usr/bin/vi`, `/usr/bin/emacs`, or `/usr/bin/nano` (fully qualified path to prevent another Mac svn related bug).

From your reply to Richard, you state your `.bash_profile` looks like this:

```
export SVN_EDITOR=svn
```

In this case, `svn ci` tries to launch the following:

```
$ svn svn-commit.tmp
Unknown command: 'svn-commit.tmp'
Type 'svn help' for usage.
```

and there is your "Unknown command" message.

Answer (score 1):

I did resolve it and in my
opinion it might be helpful to other users at some point in the future.

I tried svn ci somefile -m "my comment" thereby only committing a single file
and making my comment part of the commit message. This removed the strange
behavior from SVN. I have been using SVN since 2007 and have never seen this
before but I also never had a Mac before. Anyway, I do think this is a valid issue

Comment: Not surprising that if you don't invoke the editor (by using -m) you won't invoke the error.  Commiting only single files is irrelevant.  As described by the OP, this is not an SVN issue, but rather a configuration issue.