# SVN_EDITOR in windows + git bash + svn

Tags: windows, svn, git-bash

I am trying to live with Windows (at least have to on working environment)... And I do not like cygwin actually. I am using git-bash as minimal env.
I would like to use vim as my favourite editor. After setting SVN_EDITOR to vim

```
export SVN_EDITOR=/bin/vim
```

And I have stopped on the error

```
'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
svn: E200012: system('C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/vim svn-prop.tmp') returned 1
```

Setting vim to some more stylish dir, playing slashes and quotes didn't help. Also finally I have looked throw those issues on stackoverflow, but with no success

[svn errors out strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629327/svn-errors-out-strangely)
[Getting error trying to commit using Subversion on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008609/subversion-getting-error-trying-to-commit-on-mac-os-x)

Finally I've resolved issue by following. Hope that helps to anybody.

```
export SVN_EDITOR=bash /bin/vim --noplugins
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the spaces and the parentheses in your path:

```
export SVN_EDITOR='C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim74/gvim.exe'
```

Otherwise , you'll get `No such file or directory` for not having escaped spaces and `` sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(' `` if you forgot to escape the parentheses in your path.